# why php's str_replace mess up the strings with special chars

Tags: php, string

why php's str_replace and many other string functions  mess up the strings with special chars such ('é' 'à' ..) ? and how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

str_replace is not multi-byte (unicode) aware. use the according mb_* functions instead

in your place [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) sounds like the right  option. you could as well just use the PCRE regex functions and specifying the `X` flag

Answer (score 1):

PHP wasn't developed from the ground up to natively support UTF8. It may be useful to instead of specify the character literal, specify the entity reference / hex code of that in your replacement, eg \x3094 and replace that, I think it's more consistently supported.

Though it would help seeing your direct issue at hand, with more code.